# Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected token : Need help changing image src inside parent div with dynamic images

Tags: php, jquery, src

I am theming a wordpress site with a page called "Team Members". Each team member has a parent div with some information about the member, along with an image. When the mouse enters the parent div, I'd like the image to change. Inside my .php file, I've added some jquery to accomplish this, however when I upload the file and reload the page to test this, I see this error in my console: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :". When I inspect the script in my inspector, it appears the error is the colon after the https (var img =  https://). I don't know how fix this or how to get around this -- can anyone help?

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post) {
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post->team_member_photo, 'large')[0];
$hover_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post->team_member_hover_photo, 'large')[0];        
?>
        <div class="member">
        <img class="photo" src="<?php echo $image; ?>">

        <?php echo
        "<script type='text/javascript'> 
        var img =  $image
        var hover = $hover_image

        jQuery('.member')
        .mouseover(function(){ 
        jQuery('.photo').attr('src', hover)
        })

        .mouseout(function(){ 
        jQuery('.photo').attr('src', image);
         });
       </script>";
        ?>

       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

$image and $hover must be quoted in javascript part of your code like this

```
    var img =  '$image';
    var hover = '$hover_image';
```

Comment: doing that got rid of the syntax error but now on mouseover all image src's change to become that last team members photo. And on mouseout, all the photos disappear! Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: @AFarkas your question was about "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token" - and this is the answer that fixed this issue. If you have another issues you can create one more question